# Filtering smart-table on transformed data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

Apologies in advance, I am not a very experienced JS programmer, and even less so with AngularJS, but am trying to make some improvements on a legacy codebase that is using Angular 1.5.9 and Smart Table to display information from a database.

I've read all about `st-search` and `st-safe-src` vs. `st-table`, etc., but I am having trouble filtering on my table, since there are transformations happening on the underlying data before it gets displayed. The `ng-repeat` variable in my case is `transaction`, which has various fields to hold information for that transaction, such as `payee`, which holds a UUID pointing to another database document. In the app, we display the name of that payee using a function from another controller (`dbCtrl.getPayeeName()`), but the underlying data is the UUID. Thus, when attempting to filter with Smart Table, it does not filter on the displayed names, and only works when entering the UUID into the filter field.

A small example (with lots of the intervening bits removed, but hopefully enough to demonstrate my confusion):

```html
<div class="account"
     st-table="displayedTransactions"
     st-safe-src="transactions"
     disable-ng-animate>
...
<div><input st-search="payee" placeholder="search for payee" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/></div>
...
<div ng-repeat="transaction in displayedTransactions track by transaction.id"> 
...
  <div class="account__td" transaction-field-focus-name="payee">
    {{dbCtrl.getPayeeName(transaction.payee)}}
  </div>
...
</div>
```

Is there a relatively simple way to get the filtering to work for a situation like this where the displayed data is different than the underlying data? From what I'm reading in the documentation, it sounds like this might require some sort of custom plugin, which sounds like more work, but I could maybe figure out. I just wanted to see if I'm missing something obvious before heading down that route.

Comment: You should ideally be transforming your data before it returns from transactions. Then you won't also be binding to a function which is another angularjs sin because functions in bindings run every digest cycle and in a table that's bad for performance. Where in the template/scope is dbCtrl defined?

Comment: Thanks @MarkClark. That makes sense on transforming the data before it comes back rather than during display. Unfortunately this is a legacy codebase that I don't really want to (and probably don't have the skills to) make wholesale changes to. Apologies as I'm a complete beginner with angularjs (so this might not be a correct answer), but dbCtrl is defined in its own controller JS file as `angular.module('financier').controller('dbCtrl', function (...,){}`

Comment: Actually, now that I'm looking around at things from a different perspective, this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26990446/1435788) I think describes what I'm trying to accomplish, and I might be able to follow it to develop a custom filtering function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circling back on this, I was able to accomplish what I needed using the `st-set-filter` attribute as described in the [Strict mode filtering](https://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#filter-strict-mode) section of the documentation, as well as [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26990446/1435788) from laurent back in 2014.

Essentially, I added `st-set-filter="transactionFilters"` to my `table` in my html template, as well as `input` tags with `st-search="prop_to_search"` attributes. Then in my applications module (I put this in one of the controllers, not sure if that's totally correct) I defined a filter such as below. `expression` gets passed into this code as an object with string values for whatever you typed in, so if you had three search fields, you'd get an object like:

```js
{
  "prop_to_search1": "value1",
  "prop_to_search2": "value2",
  "prop_to_search3": "value3"
}
```

In the filter function, I wrote an `if` block for each property that could come in, and then do my custom transformations and pattern matching there. This way, I have full control over the eventual matching, and rather than searching on the UUID, I can do something like `$rootScope.dbCtrl.getPayeeName(uuidToSearch)` instead. This is all acceptably performant in my use case, but I could probably cache those database lookups as a potential optimization.

```js
angular.module('myApp').filter('transactionFilters', function($rootScope, $filter){
  return function(array, expression){
    // console.log(`expression is: ${JSON.stringify(expression, null, 4)}`)
      return array.filter(function(val, index){
        // in this function's context, `expression` is an object with
        // the active filters entered in each field; `val` is the data
        // representation of each row of the table

        // if this function returns true, the row will match and smart-table
        // will show it, otherwise it will be hidden

        // define matches all at once, check them all, then return
        // a big logical AND on all of them

        let accountMatch = true;
        let payeeMatch = true;
        let categoryMatch = true;

        if (expression.account) {
          uuidToSearch = val.account  // this is the account UUID
          strToSearch = $rootScope.dbCtrl.getAccountName(uuidToSearch).toLowerCase();  // convert to an account name (we could memoize this to improve performance)
          if (strToSearch) {
            // if the account had a name (it always should, but catch in case)
            // then check if the row's account contains the text entered in the filter field
            accountMatch = strToSearch.includes(expression.account.toLowerCase());
          } else {
            accountMatch = false;
          }
        }

        if (expression.payee){
          if (val.payee) {
            uuidToSearch = val.payee
            strToSearch = $rootScope.dbCtrl.getPayeeName(uuidToSearch).toLowerCase();
          }

          if (strToSearch) {
            payeeMatch = strToSearch.includes(expression.payee.toLowerCase());
          } else {
            payeeMatch = false;
          }
        }

        if (expression.category) {
          if (val.category) {
            strToSearch = $rootScope.dbCtrl.getCategoryName(val.category, val.date).toLowerCase()
            categoryMatch = strToSearch.includes(expression.category.toLowerCase())
          } else {
            categoryMatch = false;
          }
        }

        return (
          accountMatch && 
          payeeMatch &&
          categoryMatch
        )
    })
  }
});
```